# First digit only descending

Tags: android, sql, database

I coudn't imagine why my score is not descending. It was the first digit only to sort. help me guys to analyze this code and tell me whats wrong also the answer.

```
   public String getData() {    
   Cursor c= ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_NAME, KEY_SCORE},  
null, null, null, null, KEY_SCORE +" DESC");
   String result = "";


int iname = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);
int iscore = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SCORE);

for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
    result = result +  c.getString(iname) + "    "+   c.getInt(iscore)+ "\n";

 }

 return result;

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably that `KEY_SCORE` is being stored as a string and not as a number.

There is more than one way to fix this.  Cast the score to an integer or float:

```
cast(Key_Score as float) desc
```

Or, if it is an integer with no leading 0s, the following trick works:

```
len(Key_Score) desc, key_score desc
```

However, in some databases the `len()` function might be spelled `length()` or something else.

Comment: @KrisMacapia . . . You have the label "sql" on this question.  This is SQL syntax, so you would put it where the query is in the `order by` clause.  Possibly it would work where the `KEY_SCORE + "DESC"` is.

Comment: is this your talking about "SQL" public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
   db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +               
          KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT  NULL, " +
                KEY_SCORE + "INTEGER" );
     
     
   
   }

Comment: That's the create table statement.  It seems that KEY_SCORE is being declared as an integer, so the order by should work.

Comment: sir can you give me example using your solution,this one len(Key_Score) desc, key_score desc. please sir